# Merge data from several columns in pivot

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot

I need to count how many times a given input data is found in four different columns and summarize that in a pivot table. There are other columns in the data table that I also want to be able to track in the pivot table. How can I easiest count the number of entries, such as pictured in the attached?
[Columns MQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gl2g.jpg)?

/E

Answer (score 0):

## Here are a number of ways to count cells in Excel:

> ### Cell Counting Techniques
>
> Excel provides many ways to count cells in a range that meet various
>   criteria:
>
> - The DCOUNT function. The data must be set up in a table, and a separate criterion range is required.
> - The COUNT function. Simply counts the number of cells in a range that contain a number.
> - The COUNTA function. Counts the number of non-empty cells in a range.
> - The COUNTBLANK function. Counts the number of empty cells in a range.
> - The COUNTIF function. Very flexible, but often not quite flexible enough.
> - An array formula. Useful when the other techniques won't work.
>
> ### Formula Examples
>
> Listed below are some formula examples that demonstrate various
>   counting techniques. These formula all use a range named data.
>
> To count the number of cells that contain a negative number:
>
> ```
> =COUNTIF(data,"<0")
> ```
>
> To count the number of cells that contain the word "yes" (not case
>   sensitive):
>
> ```
> =COUNTIF(data,"yes")
> ```
>
> To count the number of cells that contain any text:
>
> ```
> =COUNTIF(data,"*")
> ```
>
> To count the number of cells that contain text that begins with the
>   letter "s" (not case-sensitive):
>
> ```
> =COUNTIF(data,"s*")
> ```
>
> To count the number of cells that contain the letter "s" (not
>   case-sensitive):
>
> ```
> =COUNTIF(data,"*s*")
> ```
>
> To count the number of cells that contain either "yes" or "no" (not
>   case-sensitive):
>
> ```
> =COUNTIF(data,"yes")+COUNTIF(data,"no")
> ```
>
> To count the number of three-letter words:
>
> ```
> =COUNTIF(data,"???")
> ```
>
> To count the number of cells that contain a value between 1 and 10:
>
> ```
> =COUNTIF(data,">=1")-COUNTIF(data,">10")
> ```
>
> To count the number of unique numeric values (ignores text entries):
>
> ```
> =SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(data,data)>0,1,0))
> ```
>
> To count the number of cells that contain an error value (this is an
>   array formula, entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter):
>
> ```
> =SUM(IF(ISERR(data),1,0))
> ```

**Source**: [spreadsheetpage.com: Cell Counting Techniques](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/cell_counting_techniques/)